# How to reorder elements by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I got 6 divs, and their current order is 1 to 6, how do I reorder them to make it become 612345?

I've tried to store them into a variable and use `getElementsByClassName`, then use the `slice` method and the `insertAdjacentElement` method but it couldn't work...

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.reorder');
const elm = document.getElementsByClassName('items');
const lastIndexOfElm = elm.length -1

function reorder() {
  let newElm = [...elm].slice(0, lastIndexOfElm);

  elm[lastIndexOfElm].insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newElm);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', reorder)
```

```html
<button class="reorder">Reorder</button>
<div class="items">1</div>
<div class="items">2</div>
<div class="items">3</div>
<div class="items">4</div>
<div class="items">5</div>
<div class="items">6</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to move the last item of ".items" to the first item, this code may help you.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.reorder');
const elm = document.getElementsByClassName('items');
const lastIndexOfElm = elm.length -1

function reorder() {
  let lastElm = elm[lastIndexOfElm];
  elm[lastIndexOfElm].remove();
  
  document.body.insertBefore(lastElm, elm[0]);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', reorder)
```

```html
<button class="reorder">Reorder</button>
<div class="items">1</div>
<div class="items">2</div>
<div class="items">3</div>
<div class="items">4</div>
<div class="items">5</div>
<div class="items">6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not work for your situation, but another possibility is putting them all in a flexbox and using the CSS `order` property to change the ordering:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="order: -1">1</div> <!-- first -->
  <div style="order: 10">2</div> <!-- last -->
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Then in Javascript you only need to adjust the CSS style's `order` property to change the ordering dynamically.